# Start activity from Service through notification and get result back in service

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am connecting BLE Device to phone, before connecting this device I want to connect this only if user verify this from other activity, I am showing notification when device found and start a Activity with verify button on this page, Till user clicks on verify button on the activity I want to pause the execution of onLeScan method in the service and after verification device will connect

My code is :

```
   public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {

        Log.i(TAG, "BluetoothLeService::onLeScan " + device.getAddress()
                + " name: " + device.getName());

  //We are creating notification here

   NotificationManager notificationManager =
                 (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                  "Notification!",
                  System.currentTimeMillis());
        String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
        String notificationText = "http://google.com/";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent
          = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
            0, myIntent,
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),
           notificationTitle,
           notificationText,
           pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);

        if (Verified) {
    if (connect(device.getAddress())) {
    } else {
        //Skip to connect
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You need another entry point to your service that the activity calls when verified.  You can not stall the onLeScan callback like this, just store the state and get out of it even doing the notification is possibly dodgy.

Comment: Not clear, Please explain